# Get one letter on two from a string

Tags: php

I have a string like :

> 12121212

I want to get only 1111, the first letter, then the third, then the fifth ... one letter on two.

Is there any function for this ? I am using str_split then I take the first letter of my array, but it's not very clean. Thanks.

This is my code for now, but it's not very flexible :

```
function loop_n_letter($string, $n)
{
    $return = '';
    $array = str_split($string);

    foreach ($array as $i => $row)
    {
       if ($i % $n == 0)
       {
           $return .= $row[0];
       }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you have tried? You can use a loop to complete this

Comment: Ok my function seems more flexible I write it on Stack ... but I am looking for a native PHP function if one exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that you can get a character of a string by simply calling the specific index of the string. Try using a for loop like so:

```
$string = '12121212';
$length = strlen($string);
$result = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i = $i + 2) {
    $result .= $string[$i];
}
die($result);
```

You can change the index and the increment to get different parts of the string

Comment: I would put `strlen($string)` to a variable and call it that way; it's more efficient as each iteration it doesn't do a function call to `strlen`.

Comment: I doubt you would see much performance impact from that change. PHP internally keeps track of the length of string variables.

Comment: True for this practice, and I like your answer ! So simple ! thanks !

Comment: @Vincent please mark this answer as correct for this question so the question will be marked as answered

Answer (score 4):

Here's one with regular expressions:

```
$str = '12121212';
echo preg_replace('<(.)(.)>', '$1', $str);
```

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly so this solution would be slower than the accepted?

Comment: And I would inline a variable to make it really one-line solution :D

Comment: I was curious and ran a benchmark. Actually, except for very short strings, regex can be faster than the accepted solution and at least in the same order of magnitude. Depends on the PHP version, though. See results: http://3v4l.org/hFUtU

Answer (score 2):

For PHP >= 5.5.0

```
$result = implode(
    '',
    array_column(
        str_split($myString, $n),
        $n - 1
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specialized case, you could use implode() and explode():

```
$string=implode(explode('2', '121212'));
echo $string;
```

Otherwise, you could use a loop:

```
$start='121212';
$string = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= strlen($start); $i++) {
    if($i &1){
        $string .= substr($start,$i,1);
    }
}
echo $string;
```

Comment: Nice for the one row answer ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at rewriting your function:

```
function loop_n_letter($string) {
  $output = '';
  if (! is_string($string)) $string = (string) $string;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i += 2) {
        $output .= $string[$i];
    }
    return $output;
}

loop_n_letter('12121212');
```

As someone else has pointed out you can use the array-style syntax to call characters at a specific position, so in the example about `$string[1]` would be `2`.

Comment: I think this line: `$output .= $string[0];` needs to be updated to `$output .= $string[$i];`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid string to array conversion (and then back to string):

```
$string = '12121212';
$stringLength = strlen($string);
$resultString = '';

for ($i=0; $i<$stringLength; $i+=2) {
    $resultString .= substr($string, $i, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex Solution: `/(\d)(?:\d)/` - capture first digit but not the following digit `?:` = non capturing

```
preg_match_all('/(\d)(?:\d)/', '12121212', $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Outputs

```
array (size=4)
    0 => string '1' (length=1)
    1 => string '1' (length=1)
    2 => string '1' (length=1)
    3 => string '1' (length=1)
```

or string

```
$result = preg_replace('/(\d)(?:\d)/', "$1", '12121212');
```

Outputs

```
string '1111' (length=4)
```